# Fetching data from firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch the data for website using java script.
Problem I am getting is that I am unable to get the key of 
Users-->Customers-->Key-->(name, phone).
I am unable to find a syntax of it

[image: Database image]

Code I am trying is

```
 var fireheading = document.getElementById("fireHeading");


var firebaseHeadingRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users").child("Customers").child(uid).child("name");



firebaseHeadingRef.on('value', function(datasnapShot){
    fireHeading.innerText = datasnapShot.val();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get data from Firebase in javascript, you would do this:

```
var fireHeading = document.getElementById("fireHeading");
// "key" is the customer key
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Users/Customers/" + key);

ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
// Contains all data from Firebase
var data = snapshot.val();
// Has customer name
var customerName = data.Name;
// Has customer phone
var customerPhone = data.Phone;

// Append data to view
fireHeading.innerText = customerName;

});
```

This should work.